# Mediapipe's output 'multi_hand_landmarks' not working in the code

Tags: python, jupyter, index-error, gesture-recognition, mediapipe

the line in question is line 2
Its not allowing the hand Left-Right Recognition

```
mp_hands.HandLandmark.WRIST
result.multi_hand_landmarks[1] 
result.multi_handedness[0].classification[0].index == num
result.multi_handedness[0].classification[0].score
def getLabel(index,hand,result):
    output = None
    for idx, classification in enumerate(result.multi_handedness):
        if classification.classification[0].index == index:
            
            
            label = classification.classification[0].label
            score = classification.classification[0].score
            text = '{} {}'.format(label,round(score,3))
            
            coords = tuple(np.multiply(
                np.array((hand.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.WRIST].x, hand.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.WRIST].y)),
            [640,480]).astype(int))
               
    return output 
getLabel(num, hand, result)
```

```
File "f:\Codes\AIML\jupyter-notebook\hand-detection-mediapipe\handDetection.py", line 41, in <module>
    result.multi_hand_landmarks[1] 
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

this is the error shown.  Sometimes this error is also thrown
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.